# Good Quant-Finance Interview Questions

Tags: big-list

I know there's the book by the late Mark Joshi and there is a lot of content on the internet. I thought it could be beneficial to additionally start a thread here  where we could all share the most interesting interview questions in Quant finance that we have encountered (i.e. a community wiki question: each answer should include one interview question (ideally with an answer): similar to "Good quant finance jokes").

Even if there might be some duplication with other resources, perhaps the added benefit of this thread would be:

1. The thread will reflect the questions that are "currently" in fashion
2. It might add value to the quant.stackexchange website as a resource for Quants and aspiring Quants

Happy to receive constructive criticism, if others don't feel this is a good idea.

Comment: Cool idea and thanks for the self flag Jan. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one that I got a long time ago in a quant interview:

**Question**:
If $x = \{ x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \}$ are i.i.d. draws from a random variable $X \sim {\mathbb U}(0,1)$, calculate

\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) - \min(x) \; ]
\end{align}

**Answer**:
I've got two fun solutions to this problem, by CDF and by Integration:

1. **CDF $\to$ PDF**

As expectation is a linear operator, we can re-write the desired quantity as the sum of two expectations
\begin{equation}
\label{minMaxUniform}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] - {\mathbb E}[ \; \min(x) \; ]
\end{equation}

Since $X \sim {\mathbb U}(0,1)$ is symmetical around 0.5, these must be related by
\begin{equation}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] = 1 - {\mathbb E}[ \; \min(x) \; ]
\end{equation}
and we can express the desired expectation in terms of a single quantity
\begin{equation}
2 \times {\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] - 1
\end{equation}

To calculate the expectation of the maximum of $n$ draws from $X$, let us consider $\max(x)$ as its own random variable, and calculate its probability distribution, $P( \max(x) = k )$ for $0 \leq k \leq 1$.

The probability that $P( \max(x) \leq k )$ is simply the probability that all draws $x_i$ are less than or equal to k, $P( x_i \leq k \; \forall \; i \in n )$ - and since each draw is independent, we can re-express this as a product of independent terms
\begin{align}
P( \max(x) \leq k ) &= P( x_i \leq k \; \forall \; i \in n )\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n P( x_i \leq k )\\
&= k^n
\end{align}

$P( \max(x) \leq k )$ is the cdf of $\max(x)$, and we can use the well-known expression to calculate its pdf
\begin{align}
P( \max(x) = k ) &= {\frac \partial {\partial k}} P( \max(x) \leq k )\\
&= n \cdot k^{n-1}
\end{align}

Having calculated the pdf of $\max(x)$, we can calculate its expectation in the usual way
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] &= \int_{k=0}^{1} p( \max(x) = k ) \cdot k \cdot dk\\
&= \int_{0}^{1} n \cdot k^{n-1} \cdot k \cdot dk\\
&= \left[ {\frac n {n+1}} k^{n+1} \right]^1_0\\
&= {\frac n {n+1}}
\end{align}

Putting this all together,
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) - \min(x) \; ] &= {\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] - {\mathbb E}[ \; \min(x) \; ]\\
&= 2 \times {\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] - 1\\
&= {\frac {2n} {n+1}} - 1\\
&= {\frac {n-1} {n+1}}
\end{align}
which is the answer

2. **Integration**

An alternative method to calculate ${\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ]$ is to integrate over each $x_i$. By symmetry, the probability of any of $n$ variables $x_i$ being the maximum is ${\frac 1 n}$, so we integrate over the region in the $n$-dimensional space for which $x_1$ is the maximum and multiply by $n$
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] &= \Bigl( \int_0^1 \Bigr)^{n} \max(x) \prod_{i=1}^n dx_i\\
&= n \cdot \int_{x_1=0}^1 x_1 \Bigl( \int_0^{x_1} \Bigr)^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^n dx_i\\
&= n \cdot \int_{x_1=0}^1 x_1 \prod_{i=1}^n \Bigl( \left[ x_i \right]^{x_1}_0 \Bigr)^{n-1} dx_1\\
&= n \cdot \int_{x_1=0}^1 x_1^n \cdot dx_1\\
&= n \cdot \left[ {\frac 1 {n+1}} x_1^{n+1}\right]_0^1\\
&= {\frac n {n+1}}
\end{align}

And so using the logic from the final step of the earlier solution,

\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) - \min(x) \; ] &= 2 \times {\mathbb E}[ \; \max(x) \; ] - 1\\
&= {\frac {2n} {n+1}} - 1\\
&= {\frac {n-1} {n+1}}
\end{align}

Comment: hi was this question for trading or quantitative research/structuring etc?

Answer (score 7):

To start the thread, let me share the most recent interview question I have been asked:

**Question**: Denote standard Brownian motion as $W(t)$. Compute the probability that:

$$ \mathbb{P}(W(1)>0 \cap W(2)>0) $$

**Answer**: Using the independence of increments property, we have $W(2) = W(2-1) + W(1)$. Denote $W(2-1)$ as $Y$ and $W(1)$ as $X$. Then:

$$ \mathbb{P}(W(1)>0 \cap W(2-1)+W(1)>0)=\mathbb{P}(X>0 \cap Y+X)>0)=\mathbb{P}(X>0 \cap Y>-X) $$

By definition of Brownian motion, the independent increments are jointly Normally distributed. So $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal with density $f_{X,Y}(u,v)$. We can write:

$$\mathbb{P}(X>0 \cap Y>-X)=\int_{u=0}^{u=\infty}\int_{v=-u}^{v=\infty}f_{X,Y}(u,v)dv du$$

The final step is to draw the domain of the double integral: $X>0$ means we're interested in the right-hand side of the cartesian $X,Y$ plot. Then with $Y>-X$, this further carves out the area below the line $Y=(-X)$ on the right-hand side of the $X,Y$ plot: i.e. we cut the "bottom $1/4$" of the right-hand half. So we are left with $3/4$ of $1/2$ of the $X,Y$ domain, which is $3/8$. Since the jointly normal PDF is a symmetrical cone centred on $x=0, y=0$, the double integral is actually equal to $3/8$ by symmetry.

Comment: I believe I have seen this one in Joshi's book

Comment: There will inherently be some duplication here. But at least it'll be interesting to see which questions are still being asked these days compared to ten years ago.

Comment: @JanStuller hi was this question for trading or quantitative research/structuring etc?

Comment: @Marco: quantitative role, model validation.

Answer (score 6):

**Question:** A contract pays
$$ P(T,T+\tau) - K$$
at $T$, where $K$ is fixed and $P(\cdot,S)$ is the price of a  $S$-maturity zero-coupon bond (ZCB).

What is $K$ for which the contract's time $t$ price is null?

**Answer:**

*Replication pricing:*

At time $t$, we go *long* *one* $T+\tau$-maturity ZCB and *short* $ P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau)$ $T$-maturity ZCB's.

Time $t$ cost of this position is $0$ as:

$$ (-1)\cdot P(t,T+\tau) +  P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau)\cdot P(t,T) = 0.  $$

At time $T$, as the shorted bond matures, we have a flow of
$$ - P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau). $$

But we are also expecting $1$ dollar flow at $T+\tau$, whose price at time $T$ is:

$$ P(T,T+\tau). $$

Hence, the $t$ price of payout (at time $T$)

$$ P(T,T+\tau)  - P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau) $$

is $0$. This is of course exactly our contract with

$$ K = P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau). $$

*Pricing under $T$-forward measure:*

$$V_t = P(t,T)\mathbf{E}^{T}_t[P(T,T+\tau) - K]$$

Setting $V_t$ to $0$ implies:

$$K =  \mathbf{E}^{T}_t[P(T,T+\tau)]$$

As $P(t,T+\tau)$ is a traded asset, under $T$-forward measure, process
$$  \left(P(t,T)^{-1} P(t,T+\tau)\right)_{t\geq 0}$$
is a martingale, which leads to:
$$\mathbf{E}^{T}_t[P(T,T)^{-1} P(T,T+\tau)] = P(t,T)^{-1} P(t,T+\tau).$$
Due to $P(T,T)=1$, we have:

$$K =  \mathbf{E}^{T}_t[P(T,T+\tau)] = P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau)$$

*Pricing under money market account  measure:*

$$V_t = \beta_t\mathbf{E}_t[\beta_T^{-1} (P(T,T+\tau) - K)]$$

Setting $V_t$ to $0$ implies:

$$K =  \mathbf{E}_t[\beta_T^{-1}]^{-1}\mathbf{E}_t[\beta_T^{-1} P(T,T+\tau)]$$

$$ = P(t,T)\mathbf{E}_t\left[\beta_T^{-1} \mathbf{E}_T[\beta_T \beta_{T+\tau}^{-1} ] \right] $$

$$  = P(t,T)^{-1}\mathbf{E}_t\left[ \mathbf{E}_T[ \beta_{T+\tau}^{-1} ] \right] $$

$$ = P(t,T)^{-1}\mathbf{E}_t\left[  \beta_{T+\tau}^{-1} \right]  $$

$$ = P(t,T)^{-1}P(t,T+\tau), $$

using [tower property of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) in the penultimate equality.

(*Note:* not necessarily a recent question, but expected to be asked - I flunked the replication pricing part that the interviewer was obviously enamored with; this is covered by both [Brigo/Mercurio's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540221494), in the context of FRA pricing, and by [Andersen/Piterbarg's book](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11408-011-0157-y), forward bond price.)

Comment: hi was this question for trading or quantitative research/structuring etc?

Comment: @Mining quantitative analyst

Answer (score 4):

**Question**
Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a $n\times n$ covariance matrix such that all diagonal elements are equal to 1, and the non-diagonal ones to $\rho$ with $-1\leq\rho\leq1$. Which range of values is admissible for $\rho$?

**Solution 1**
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables with unit variance and pairwise correlation $\rho$ for any $i\not= j$. Let $Y:=\sum_iX_i$ then:
\begin{align}
    \notag
    V\left(Y\right)
    &=\sum_{i=1}^nV\left(X_i\right)+\sum_{i\not=j}Cov(X_i,X_j)
    \\
    &=n+n(n-1)\rho
\end{align}
The variance of $Y$ is positive, therefore:
\begin{align}
n+n(n-1)\rho\geq0 
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \boxed{\rho\geq\frac{1}{1-n}}
\end{align}

**Solution 2**
The covariance matrix $C$ cen be written as

$$
C=(1-\rho)\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector composed of $\sqrt{\rho}$. A covariance matrix must be positive semidefinite , hence its smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_0$, must be $\lambda_0\geq 0$.

The eigenvalues are found from the roots of the determinant equation:

$$
\mathrm{det}(\Sigma-\lambda\mathbf{I})=\mathrm{det}((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T)=0
$$

By the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), the determinant is found as

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{det}(\Sigma-\lambda\mathbf{I})&=\left(\mathbf{u}^T\left((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{u}\right)\mathbf{det}\left((1-\rho-\lambda)\mathbf{I}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\lambda+(n-1)\rho\right)\left(1-\rho-\lambda\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

The first eigenvalue is $\lambda_1=1-\rho$, with multiplicity $n-1$. The second eigenvalue is $\lambda_2=1+(n-1)\rho$. The smallest admissible eigenvalue, zero, is reached at either $\rho=1$ or $\rho=-\frac{1}{n-1}$. Hence,

$$
\boxed{-\frac{1}{n-1}\leq\rho\leq1}
$$

Comment: How do we know this inequality is best possible ?  Thx

Comment: Thinking about my own question: you can generate an inequality like this using any linear combination of the $X_i$.  Indeed it does seem that the ‘best’ inequality occurs when all the coefficients are 1.

Comment: @dm63 I don't have a clear proof for the general case so I have restricted the problem to the case where the associated variance matrix is the unit matrix.

Answer (score 2):

**Background**
Consider the affine Linear Gauss Markov (LGM) model for Interest Rates, characterized by a single-factor state variable $x_t$ with normal dynamics...
\begin{align}
\text{d}x_t&=\sigma(t)\text{d}W_t
\end{align}
... specified in a measure under which the price process $N_t$:
\begin{align}
N_t&:=\frac{1}{P(0,t)}e^{H(t)x_t+a(t)},
\end{align}
is a valid *numéraire*, where $P$ is the price of a zero-coupon bond, while $H(t)$ and $a(t)$ are two deterministic functions. Note this model is also known as the *Hagan and Woodward parameterization* of Hull-White, see this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/14372/20454).

**Question**
Determine the structure of the function $a(t)$ to ensure the LGM model is arbitrage-free.

**Answer**
We know a model is arbitrage-free if and only if there exists an equivalent martingale measure (EMM), namely a probability measure such that the price of a traded asset is equal to the conditional expectation of its discounted cash flows. The basic asset in any rate model is the zero-coupon bond, which pays $\\\$1$ at expiry. Hence our LGM model must satisfy:
$$P(0,t)=E\left(\frac{1}{N_t}\right)$$
Per the definition of $N_t$, the equivalent condition is:
$$E\left(e^{-H(t)x_t-a(t)}\right)=1\tag{1}$$
The state variable $x_t$ is normally distributed, with zero mean and total variance up to $t$ equal to:
$$\Sigma(t):=\int_0^t\sigma^2(u)\text{d}u$$
Expectation $(1)$ can be explicitly calculated, for example by invoking the Laplace transform of a normal variable, and we get:
$$\boxed{a(t) = \frac{1}{2}H^2(t)\Sigma(t)}$$
Interestingly, we note that compared to the Hull-White parameterisation, where the calibrated parameter needs to be updated whenever the curve changes to remain arbitrage-free (e.g. see the specification of the function $\theta(t)$ in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/38742/20454)), the LGM model is arbitrage-free by design provided we set the function $a(t)$ to be equal to the expression above.

Comment: hi was this question for trading or quantitative research/structuring etc?

Comment: @Marco quant research.